# Custom post type in slider front page Breaking layout

Tags: custom-post-types

In WordPress, I am pulling data in from an api and using custom post types to display in owl-slider. For some reason, my code is breaking the slider layout. I will post the code below.

```
<form>
  <section class="s-raking">
    <div class="container">

        <?php
            $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ranking',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );
        ?>

        <h2 class="title-bar" data-ranking="<?php echo $terms[0]->slug; ?>">Ranking <span><?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?></span>
            <div class="ranking-nav-btn">
              <div class="customPrevBtn4"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
              <div class="customNextBtn4"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
            </div>
        </h2>

        <div class="row no-gutters">

            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="slider-ranking owl-carousel">

                    <?php
                        foreach($terms as $term) { ?>

                    <div class="rankig-one" style='background:url(<?php the_field('bg_image', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?>) no-repeat scroll center center; background-size: cover;' data-title="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
                        <h3><?php the_field('title_normal', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?> <?php if(get_field('title_strong', 'term_' .$term->term_id )) { ?><span><?php the_field('title_strong', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?></span><?php } ?></h3>

            <ul class="ajax-content2">

                        <?php 
                        $posts = get_field('top_players', 'term_' .$term->term_id );
                        if( $posts ): ?>
                            <ul>
                            <?php $i = '1'; foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                                <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endif;  ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>
</ul><! - - end ajax-content2-->
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="filters-ranking">
                    <div class="filters-search">
                        <input type="text" class="quicksearch" placeholder="Encuentra a un jugador" />
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tabs d-flex">
                        <span class="tab">Ranking</span>
                        <span class="tab">Selecciona tu estado</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab_content">
                        <div class="tab_item">
                            <div class="filters-bar">

                                <select class="filters-select" name="position" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                    <?php
                                        $field_key = "field_5c80e92663dd1";
                                        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
                                        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                                            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="players-results" id="ajax-content"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab_item">
              <div class="players-state">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $field_key = "field_5cebb7e973218";
                        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
                        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                            echo '<li data-value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>                
              </div>      
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      

        </div>


    </div>
</section>

<?php
        if(isset($_GET["position"])){
            $position=$_GET["position"];
            // echo "select position is => ".$position;
        }
        ?> 

 </form>
```

The link to the home page is https://probeis.mx
The slider in question is:

[image]

On Closer inspection in the inspector tools, I notice the "li" information is missing after one second.

[image]

Edit:

Thanks to Mehar I have moved closer to the problem. I now have the data persisting to the page but now my slider items are all showing 2 or 3 items even though the owl carousel is set to item: 1. I am now also missing the search box to the right of the slider as seen in the image above. I will place the updated code below.

Functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_players', 'players_lpm' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_players', 'players_lpm' );
function players_lpm() {

    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $ranking = $_POST['ranking'];
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'players_lpm',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => $search,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ranking',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $ranking
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => 'position', 'value' => $position, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        'relation' => 'AND'
        )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); $i2 = '1';
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><span>'.$i2.'</span>'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    $i2++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    echo '</ul>';
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_playersmain', 'playersmain' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_playersmain', 'playersmain' );
function playersmain() {

    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $ranking = $_POST['ranking'];
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'players_lpm',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        's' => $search,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ranking',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $ranking
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array( 'key' => 'position', 'value' => $position, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
            array( 'key' => 'state', 'value' => $state, 'compare' => 'LIKE' ),
            'relation' => 'AND'
        )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); $i2 = '1';
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><span>'.$i2.'</span>'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
    $i2++; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}
```

Script.js

```
var owl8 = $( ".slider-ranking" );
    owl8.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        nav:true,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        navText:['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
        dots: false,
        //autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:4000,
        autoplayHoverPause:true
    });

    $('.customNextBtn4').click(function() {
        owl8.trigger('next.owl.carousel', [300]);
    });
    $('.customPrevBtn4').click(function() {
        owl8.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);
    });

    owl8.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
        var current = e.item.index;
        var currSl2 = $(e.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".rankig-one h3").html();
        $(".s-raking .title-bar span").html(currSl2);
        var currSl3 = $(e.target).find(".owl-item").eq(current).find(".rankig-one").attr('data-title');
        $(".s-raking .title-bar").attr('data-ranking', currSl3);
        ranking();
    });

/*for first load*/
    function ranking() {
        $(".filters-ranking .players-results").mCustomScrollbar("destroy");
        var position = $(".filters-select option:selected").val();
        var ranking = $('.s-raking .title-bar').attr('data-ranking');
        var search = $('.quicksearch').attr('data-search');
        var state = $('.players-state').attr('data-state');

        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'playersmain',
                position: position,
                ranking: ranking,
                search: search,
                state: state
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                $("#ajax-content").html(response);
                $(".filters-ranking .players-results").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollButtons:{enable:true}
                });
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data : {
                // action : 'playersmain',
                action : 'players_lpm',
                position: position,
                ranking: ranking,
                search: search,
                state: state
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                $(".ajax-content2").html(response);
            }
        });
    } 
    ranking();
```

The front-page.php data from above is still the same. Again, Thank you Mehar for getting me closer to solving this dilema.

P.D. Here is the messed up version image so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by your ajax call which is returning the empty response.
like see in your code

```
$.ajax({
            url : ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data : {
                action : 'playersmain',
                position: position,
                ranking: ranking,
                search: search,
                state: state
            },
            success : function( response ) {
                $(".ajax-content2").html(response);
            }
        });
```

This ajax call is made through `themes/probeis-child/assets/scripts.js`

Comment: i have reviewed your code, also no content is coming from ajax.

Comment: there is also one syntax error that you are missing closing tag for <ul class="ajax-content2"> due to this {rankig-one} class is nesting that produces the messed result.

Answer (score 0):

are you using any slider plugin,  most of the slider displays the content(Timeshift and duration) for milliseconds,so increase the display seconds(Timeshift and duration)  in 10000 milliseconds,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was two-fold. I had the wrong action in the ajax call which should have read players_lpm. That fixed the data not persisting. Additionally, I had the wrong placement of the initial form tag. I will place the edited code below. But before I do, many thanks to Mehar for his help in getting me closer to the answer.

```
<section class="" style="margin-top: 60px; padding-bottom: 0;">
<div class="concept-bar">
  <div class="container">
  <h2 class="title-bar">EJES ESTRATÉGICOS</h2>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px;">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="number-holder"><span class="eje-number">1</span>
          <h2 class="concept-item">DESAROLLO INTEGRAL DE TALENTO</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="number-holder"><span class="eje-number">2</span>
          <h2 class="concept-item">APOYO AL BEISBOL INFANTIL Y JUVENIL</h2>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="number-holder"><span class="eje-number">3</span>
          <h2 class="concept-item">IMPULSO DE CONCEPTO "BEISBOL" EN MÉXICO</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="s-raking">
    <div class="container">

        <?php
            $terms = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'ranking',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );
        ?>

        <h2 class="title-bar" data-ranking="<?php echo $terms[0]->slug; ?>">Ranking <span><?php echo $terms[0]->name; ?></span>
            <div class="ranking-nav-btn">
              <div class="customPrevBtn4"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
              <div class="customNextBtn4"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
            </div>
        </h2>

        <div class="row no-gutters">

            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="slider-ranking owl-carousel">

                    <?php
                        foreach($terms as $term) { ?>

                    <div class="rankig-one" style='background:url(<?php the_field('bg_image', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?>) no-repeat scroll center center; background-size: cover;' data-title="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>">
                        <h3><?php the_field('title_normal', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?> <?php if(get_field('title_strong', 'term_' .$term->term_id )) { ?><span><?php the_field('title_strong', 'term_' .$term->term_id ); ?></span><?php } ?></h3>

            <!-- <ul class="ajax-content2"> -->

                        <?php 
                        $posts = get_field('top_players', 'term_' .$term->term_id );
                        if( $posts ): ?>
                            <ul>
                            <?php $i = '1'; foreach( $posts as $post): ?>
                                <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $i; ?> <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                            <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
                            </ul>
                            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        <?php endif;  ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="filters-ranking">
                    <div class="filters-search">
                        <input type="text" class="quicksearch" placeholder="Encuentra a un jugador" />
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tabs d-flex">
                        <span class="tab">Ranking</span>
                        <span class="tab">Selecciona tu estado</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab_content">
                        <div class="tab_item">
                            <div class="filters-bar">

                                <select class="filters-select" name="position" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                                    <?php
                                        $field_key = "field_5c80e92663dd1";
                                        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
                                        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                                            echo '<option value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</option>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>

                            </div>
                            <div class="players-results" id="ajax-content"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab_item">
              <div class="players-state">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                        $field_key = "field_5cebb7e973218";
                        $field = get_field_object($field_key);
                        foreach ( $field['choices'] as $k => $v ) {
                            echo '<li data-value="' . $k . '">' . $v . '</li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>                
              </div>      
            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      

        </div>


    </div>
</section>

<?php
        if(isset($_GET["position"])){
            $position=$_GET["position"];
            // echo "select position is => ".$position;
        }
        ?> 

 </form>
```